# Filtering regions in Iceland

Tags: arcgis-platform, power-bi

I'm working with ArcGIS in Power BI.

My objective is to be able to filter my report based on regions in Iceland, such as this:

[image]

I'm having a hard time finding a good way to do this.

In an ArcGIS map, and the regions appear here:

[image]

How do I filter based on these regions?

I can't choose them in the map. I could perhaps create a column that specifies the region. For example, a records is logged in the "Southwestern region" then ultimately I could filter to that.

I reckon this would be similar to using States in the US, but I haven't managed to do this like that.

Comment: attribute required on region. I think you answered your own question.

Answer (score 1):

You need a shapefile that contains the polygons for each region so that you can modify the symbology properties of that layer.

Download the file here: https://stacks.stanford.edu/file/druid:dq155fd3935/data.zip

Then, load the shapefile into GIS and modify the symbology properties such that all unique values in the region field (name_1) are colored differently. (https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/help/mapping/layer-properties/unique-value.htm)